# Trigger mail on cell edits after saving workbook

Tags: vba, email, events, outlook

I found code on the internet which triggers an e-mail on cell edit, at the sheet level.

However, I want to trigger an e-mail only after saving the workbook after changes are made, for the entire workbook.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Updated by Extendoffice 2017/9/12
    Dim xRgSel As Range
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xMailItem As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set xRg = Range("A2:E11")
    Set xRgSel = Intersect(Target, xRg)
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    If Not xRgSel Is Nothing Then
        Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set xMailItem = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
        xMailBody = "Cell(s) " & xRgSel.Address(False, False) & _
          " in the worksheet '" & Me.Name & "' were modified on " & _
          Format$(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy") & " at " & Format$(Now, "hh:mm:ss") & _
          " by " & Environ$("username") & "."

        With xMailItem
            .To = "Email Address"
            .Subject = "Worksheet modified in " & ThisWorkbook.FullName
            .Body = xMailBody
            .Attachments.Add (ThisWorkbook.FullName)
            .Display
        End With
        Set xRgSel = Nothing
        Set xOutApp = Nothing
        Set xMailItem = Nothing
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: One approach would be to (eg) on workbook open save a copy of the workbook and then on save compare the content between the two workbooks to look for changes. If you just log changes cell-by-cell then you need to account for users reverting edits etc.

Answer (score 0):

When the worksheet is changed you can set a boolean flag which can be used to make a decision whether to send an email when the workbook is closed.

```
Dim flag as Boolean = False

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  flag = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel as Boolean) 
    If flag = False Then 
      SendEmail()
    End If 
End Sub

Private Sub SendEmail()
   Dim xRgSel As Range
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xMailItem As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set xRg = Range("A2:E11")
    Set xRgSel = Intersect(Target, xRg)
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    If Not xRgSel Is Nothing Then
        Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set xMailItem = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
        xMailBody = "Cell(s) " & xRgSel.Address(False, False) & _
            " in the worksheet '" & Me.Name & "' were modified on " & _
            Format$(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy") & " at " & Format$(Now, "hh:mm:ss") & _
            " by " & Environ$("username") & "."

        With xMailItem
            .To = "Email Address"
            .Subject = "Worksheet modified in " & ThisWorkbook.FullName
            .Body = xMailBody
            .Attachments.Add (ThisWorkbook.FullName)
            .Display
        End With
        Set xRgSel = Nothing
        Set xOutApp = Nothing
        Set xMailItem = Nothing
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

When the [Workbook.BeforeSave](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.beforesave) event is fired (before the workbook is saved) you can trigger an email to be sent out.